# PHP: Get the days name in lowercase?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the days name in PHP which suppose to be a simple task.

I can simply do this:

```
echo date('L');
```

This will print `Sunday` <-- Today's name.

However, I need to know if its possible to get the same day's name but in Lowercase like: `sunday` ?

Comment: wrap it inside strtolower(date('l'));

Comment: @RohitS, that prints the days's number. so for today it will print 0. Not the day's name.

Comment: see i have updated its lowercase 'l'

Comment: *"echo date('L');

This will print Sunday <-- Today's name."* - No it won't, it will print 1 or 0 if it's a leap year http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php *"L  Whether it's a leap year  1 if it is a leap year, 0 otherwise."*

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner, yes you are correct. I meant to write echo date('l');... now remove your downvote :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use [`strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php):

```
echo strtolower(date('l'));
```

Comment: that prints the days's number. so for today it will print 0. Not the day's name.

Answer (score 3):

Simple, use [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php):

```
echo strtolower(date('l'));
```

Comment: This is the exact same answer I gave ....

Comment: yea.. i already added it to comment and i do have a strtolower manual ref.. :D cheers

Comment: I have the manual ref as well. In fact, you link to a different manual than the text in your link. :D  cheers (+1, let the community decide ;)).

Comment: did you checked the link..anyways m going to delete this i guess comment serves the purpose for OP.. cheers..

Comment: in RohitS defense, he answered first but he just put his answer in the comment section lol... But i used Brat's answer. so thanks to both of you. ;)

Comment: @DavidHope haha..thats fine.. we are here to help..not to fight..happy coding.. :D

Comment: cheers mate. appreciate it.

Comment: The correct place to post solutions is as answers, never comments.  Please delete your comment.